# How to call a function in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am new to react-redux. Now I am working on a react-redux project. I want to call a function when my input changes in input tag. For this I apply "onchange" event in this like

```
 <input {...this.props}  onchange="this.callHandler(this.value)"/>
```

onchange event handler call a function "callHandler" which is define as

```
 callHandler = (value) => {
      console.log("value in input",value);
 }
```

I don't know why this function is not called.
My full code for this component is :

```
import React from 'react';

type PropsType = {
};

export default class InputComponent extends React.Component<void, PropsType, void> {
     callHandler = (value) => {
          console.log("value in input",value);
     }
  render() {
       console.log("InputComponent props",this.props);
    const inputStyle = this.props.inputStyle;
    return (
      <input {...this.props}  onchange="this.callHandler(this.value)"/>
    );
  }
}
```

I also don't know why we use {...this.props}.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prop is `onChange` instead of `onchange`. `onChange` expects a function, not a string

```
onChange={this.callHandler}

this.callHandler = event => {
  console.log('value', event.target.value)
}
```

`callHandler` gets passed an event, you can get the value of the event's target by doing `event.target.value`, as above.

`{...this.props}` means that all props from the component are passed to the input element, see [spread attributes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes) for further reading.

For example,

```
<InputComponent type="text" placeholder="foobar" />
```

Passes all props of `InputComponent` (type and placeholder in this case) to the `input` element, which can be useful when creating generic/smarter containers.

Comment: Do you know we use {...this.props} here

Comment: @Kelltontech, see the bottom half of the comment. I'm expanding it further but hopefully that gives a basic understanding for now